# Collection is 'mappedBy' a property which does not exist in the target entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, liquibase

I have a One To Many relationship between two entities

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "npm_leagues")
public class NPMLeague implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "npmleague",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<NPMStadium> npmStadiums;
}
```

```
@Table(name = "npm_stadiums")
public class NPMStadium implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "npm_league_id")
    private NPMLeague npmLeague;

}
```

i'm getting this error

> > Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource : Collection 'com.iam.app.models.NPMLeague.npmStadiums' is 'mappedBy' a property named 'NPMLeague' which does not exist in the target entity 'com.iam.app.models.NPMleague'

am i adding the relationships between the models wrong? i am using liquibase does this affect the relationships between the entities ?

Comment: npmleague != npmLeague

Comment: it is case sensitive ? i will try this